# How to Install Ubuntu on my lenovo which has four partitions

Tags: installation, partitioning, usb

I own a Lenovo Y580 Ideapad and in the process of installing Ubuntu through a USB I cannot install alongside windows as it already has four partitions:

- `/dev/sda1` (Windows 7 Loader) ntfs (Size 209MB Used 70MB)
- `/dev/sda2` (Windows 7 Loader) ntfs (Size 451577 Used Unknown)
- `/dev/sda3` ntfs (Size 27346MB Used 4114MB)
- `/dev/sda4` (Windows Recovery Environment Loader) ntfs (Size 20972MB Used 13354MB)

If possible should I delete one of these partitions to make room for Ubuntu?
How would I go about deleting it? and how would it change my computers performance in any way? Thanks in advance to any who may answer.

Answer (score 0):

We need more information on how your hard drive is configure, GPT or MBR partition table? Total size of hard drive?

Assuming its MBR, that will only allow for 4 primary partitions. So you would have to delete a 2 primary partitions and resize 1 for Ubuntu. Then in the other partition create an extended partition with a logical partition so you can add other logical partitions if you need them.

Your partition table would look something like:

```
Primary 1 - sda1 (ntfs - Windows)
Primary 2 - sda2 (ntfs - Windows)
Primary 3 - sda3 (ext4 - Ubuntu)
Primary 4 - (if needed)   

Extended Partition:
    Logical - sda4 (Linux Swap)
    Logical - sda5 (if needed)
```

This is if your hard drive is configured for MBR and if you hard drive has space for a 2nd OS. In the end you'll probably have to delete partitions to make room. Good luck.